# Updating column based on vlookup

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I have the below code that does vlookup. Checks whether the values in sheet "UG list" col A, is present in sheet "Latency" B col.

Currently I get the values pasted in sheet "UG list" itself if there is a match. But instead, I need the text "UG" to be updated in col in Q in "Latency" sheet if there is a match.

Any suggestions to implement this?

```
Sub vlookup()
Dim cl As Range, Dic As Object
Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary"): Dic.Comparemode =    vbTextCompare
With Sheets("Latency")
For Each cl In .Range("B2:B" & .Cells(Rows.count, "C").End(xlUp).Row)
    If Not Dic.exists(cl.Value) Then Dic.Add cl.Value, cl.Row
Next cl
End With
With Sheets("UG list")
For Each cl In .Range("A2:A" & .Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    If Dic.exists(cl.Value) Then cl.Offset(, 1).Value = cl.Value
Next cl
End With
Set Dic = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
With Sheets("UG list")
    For Each cl In .Range("A2:A" & .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
        If Dic.exists(cl.Value) Then
            Sheets("Latency").Cells(Dic(cl.Value), 17) = "UG"
        End If
    Next cl
End With
```

17 is the column # for Q. You already are storing the row number in the dictionary so simply used it.

Comment: awesome this works perfectly fine..one more small question..how do i do the same for other sheet as well? I mean doing vlookup in other sheets and updating "UG" in that specifc sheets colQ and keeping "UG list" as the source?

Comment: going by your logic, you will need seperate dictionaries with values and row numbers.for each sheet and then loop the ug list as you are doing, check all the dictionaries and if they exist update col Q. But if you have many sheet consider using formulas like VLOOKUP to do this instead of dictionary.